# WCF Service method working fine when run visual studio but not working from IIS, do I special config?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2013

Good morning,

I have creating a WCF web service and when i execute it from the Visual Studio it works fine, but when I deploy it and run it from the IIS, the web service methods don't seem to work, it just returns a blank page, not error not nothing. I think the problem maybe with the config file.
Please see my config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyWebService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="MyWebService.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />

      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Am I missing something on the config file?

By the way, I am using Visual Studio 2013, C#, IIS7

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by configuring SQL Server to be accessed by IIS (Application pool).

**This solved the issue.**